# Does USB core take care of freeing urb->hcpriv even if it's NOT allocated by itself?

Tags: linux-kernel, usb, libusb

I work on a customized hci controller module inside which I use `urb->hcpriv` to store private data for each `urb`. The memory is allocated by `kmalloc()` by the hci controller inside `urb_enqueue()`.

I assume I need to free it before calling `usb_hcd_giveback_urb()` to complete the URB to avoid memory leak but looks like that hangs the whole kernel. However I was not able to see where `urb->hcpriv` is freed inside usb core code.

Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 0):

After some digging I figured out USB core takes care of cleaning up `hcpriv` in case `urb->status` is set to complete (0) when `usb_hcd_giveback_urb()` is called. So you only need to free `hcpriv` explicitly when the URB is completed with failure.